# Jmete recording options

Tags: jmeter

Hello every one my question is that can jmeter record the scripts while we are running our test plan. Like i need to get the http requests from server during execution of my test and instantly update my test plan. If yes please let me know how?

Comment: check this link 

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios

Comment: yup but the main problem i have stated below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Run JMeter test plan.
- Capture the HTTP requests using Fiddler Export
- Fiddler session as JMeter test plan. Refer this [link](http://www.perftesting.co.uk/creating-jmeter-test-plans-with-fiddler/2013/03/01/)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can record JMeter test execution.

   To do so:

   - Launch JMeter instance #1
   - Choose `File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create` from the top menu
   - Under `Workbench` choose `HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click `Start`
   - Launch your main test by [running JMeter instance # 2 in command-line non-GUI mode](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) through JMeter instance #1 proxy as:

     ```
     jmeter -H localhost -P 8888 -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
     ```
2. There is no easy and obvious way to change the plan which is being executed on the fly. If you need to change specific bits consider converting some hard-coded values into dynamic [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and perform:

   - **parametrisation** - via i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
   - or **correlation** via i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Comment: yup worked but i think its not a good approach. i tell you the exact problem i am facing. i am adding an account whose id is for example 1, now this account has been added and it load that account now i want to open that account which is added after addition process.

Comment: Like  ab.com/1  the first account is added now the jmeter returns that record of id 1 from server. SO the problem is that when i run the next iteration it adds the account but the id 1 is returning from server because the script contains the id 1 parameter. I cant handle it through  regular expression extractor because the id of newly added account is returned after addition process from server. SO how can i solve this situation do i need a database access to get the id of newly added record.

Comment: Thanks alot for previous reply and see if you have best solution for above problem

Comment: You **can** get the new ID from the database via JDBC Test elements. See  [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) and referenced articles for details.

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitri